# Can someone explain to me in detail what is going on in this Ruby block?

Tags: ruby, block

Learning Ruby. Needed to create a hash of arrays. This works... but I don't quite understand what Ruby is doing. Could someone explain it in detail?

```
months = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
```

Comment: `{|...| ...}` is a block, sort of like an anonymous function in other languages (such as JavaScript), the stuff between the pipes are the block's arguments. So `{|a, b| a + b}` is sort of like `function(a, b) { return a + b }` in JavaScript.

Comment: plus one for comparing to js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the [`Hash.new`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/new/class) constructor to create a hash whose items default to the empty list. You can therefore do something like this:

```
months[2012] << 'January'
```

and the array will be created without you doing a `months[2012] = []` first.

**Short explanation**: `{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }` Is a Ruby block and as mu has mentioned, it can to some degree be compared to `function` in Javascript or `lambda` in Python. It basically is an anonymous piece of code that takes two arguments (`h`, `k`, the pipes only have the meaning to separate parameters from code) and returns a value. In this case it takes a hash and a key and sets the value of the key to a new array `[]`. It returns a reference to the hash (but that's not important in this context).

Now to `Hash.new`: It is the constructor for a `Hash`, of which I assume you already now what it is. It optionally takes a block as an argument that is called whenever a key is accessed that does not yet exist in the Hash. In the above example, the key `2012` was not accessed before, so the block is called, which creates a new array and assigns it to the key. Afterwards, the `<<` operator can work with that array instance.

Comment: could you explain whats going on between the {} and between the pipes.. sorry new to Ruby.

Comment: @Rick: Tried to add a bit of explanation, maybe this is helpful for you.